# The NTG-3 vs MKH-416 choice

Tags: microphone, sound-effects-recording, sound-design

Hi guys

Big fan of the site. I've been doing some research between the NTG-3 and the MKH-416 and am trying to decide between the two. Budget aside, is the MKH-416 worth the extra that you're paying ? I am interested in recording sound effects and the idea of the narrow pattern of the shotgun is appealing to me. I know this debate has been talked about enough, but I'm curious about what you guys think.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hi
I have used the 416 for years and would normally go for that on a shoot, but I recently bought the Rode NTG3 and I can honestly say that I love it. Perhaps not more than the 416, but certainly my mic of choice for the time being. The sound of the NTG3 is slightly warmer than the 416 and has a few degrees larger pickup pattern.
I have just done a couple of days on a sitcom and solely used the NTG3.
I also record sound effects with it and it's brilliant for that purpose as well, extremely low self noise and with it being suitable for many conditions you can get sounds in places you would have not normally wanted to put a mic. For expample, recording while having a shower (with the recorder outside of course) or in a sauna!!
Good luck with the recording and if you get the NTG I hope you enjoy using at much as I do.

Comment: @Simon, thanks for the review. I've not really considered the NTG3 (or any of the Røde mics) before, but after hearing your experiences I'd like to test them out.

Comment: @Simon, yes thank you! That was a great response.

Answer (score 1):

My take on the NTG3 - it's a fantastic mic. I've never used the MKH 416 but I also checked all the comparison material and opinions online and yeah, it seemed close enough.

The only thing with the NTG3 - you have to be aware that it's quite bassy, and it doesn't have a low cut filter. I personally don't have any problem with that, but I know some people who didn't like the mic because of that. I don't know if the MKH416 has a low cut filter, but I believe it does?

Anyway, the way I see it is that a lo cut filter is mainly useful for dialogue recordists. I only really record sound effects so I don't mind at all - can fix things in post if really necessary, and I don't have to run around with a boom pole, worrying about low frequency rumble from handling or cable noise.

However, if you have a bit of extra budget... May be worth scanning eBay for a MKH60. It's really a big step up from the NTG3/MKH416 in terms of smoothness, natural representation, transparency. It's more expensive - but on eBay I see it go sometimes for a little more than a MKH416, and in this case, the price difference is most definitely worth it over the NTG3!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has already been [answered on Gearslutz](http://www.gearslutz.com/board/post-production-forum/594631-ntg-3-vs-mkh-416-a.html) or simply [here](http://www.gearslutz.com/board/5866666-post71.html).

Answer (score 0):

NTG-3: Did anybody notice a problem with cold or/and humid conditions?

I recently read something about it somewhere.

Comment: yes earlier serial numbered ntg3s don't work too well in the cold, if at all. Thankfully you get a 10 year warranty with Rode, and they replace it as soon as possible.

Comment: This article http://www.rodemic.com/news.php?article=0023 says high humidity isn't much of an issue.

Comment: I've owned two and spoken to people who have had the same problem. If you have an early NTG-3, it could be faulty in very cold temp. My replacement is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I've been researching the same topic and have come to the conclusion that they are very similar microphones.

I've come to understand the MKH has a narrower pickup pattern and a flatter bass response.

However, on the rode website, Ric Viers does a video about the microphone and states that the microphones purpose is to knock the top shotgun off it's perch (referencing the MKH 416) - so I think it's safe to assume that for all intents and purposes, they're practically the same.

I also read an opinion somewhere (I'll try and find it again) where someone summed it up this way:

"If you're buying the microphone for yourself, get the NTG-3. If you're freelancing, get the MKH-416 because the name will attract work"

Hope this help,

Cheers

Comment: Although I think that quote is more relevant for people who record dialogue on tv/film sets, not so much for fx recording.

Comment: Completey agree with that Daan.
